# Hibernate Query Escaping (from Grails' GORM) - again

Tags: hibernate, grails, escaping

I have seen many related question, but none of them is exactly my problem.

General question: where exactly is specified how the things get escaped in Hibernate, in particular for Grails GORM?

Particular problem:

I want to execute this:

```
"WHERE extractValue(field, '//value[@my_attribute=\""+localeStr+"\"]')"
```

You can notice, the localeStr is not escaped, and included in another string of string.
How can I escape this, if possible with a parameter (something like :parameter)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here, I believe, in "bind parameters" section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying-executing). Plus general Groovy escaping.

Though, sorry, it's not clear - escape what? Do you need `localeStr` to contain a parameter, or opposite, to sanitize out any possible parameter?

Removing `":"` and `"?"` should do, as for me. Though, it's a bad idea to concatenate an untrusted `String` directly into a query anyway.

The best approach to sanitize a `String` parameter is to, er, pass it as a parameter:

```
DomainClass.findAll(
   "WHERE extractValue(field, '//value[@my_attribute=:attrValue]',
   [attrValue: localeStr])")
```

See [findAll() doc](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html).

Comment: You are right, localeStr has to be passed as parameter. But not that way... somehow else. Because :attrValue will be replaced with something like 'my string', and in that context, it will become:

"extractValue(field, '//value[@my_attribute='my string']'"

And how you can see, the '' are not the right escaping characters.